# PIGPIO wiring, basic i2c slave questions

Tags: c++, pigpio

I'm toying with pigpio and I can't find some informations:

1) I'm currently using a arduino uno to send bytes (as master) to a Rpi3 as slave, I currently use BCM2 as SDA (A4 on Uno) and BCM3 as SDL(A5 on Uno) on the Rpi.

It seems odd to use the I2C master GPIOs to perform I2C-slave, but I couldn't find any relevant information. Am I using the "good" GPIOs ?

2) If I'm, I can't receive anything from the Uno here are both sources:

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup()
{
    Wire.begin(); // join i2c bus as master
}

char str[17];

int x = 0;

void loop()
{
    sprintf(str, "Message %7d\n", x);
    if (++x > 9999999) x=0;

    Wire.beginTransmission(0x0A); 
    Wire.write(str);           
    Wire.endTransmission();    
    delay(100);
}
```

Arduino code is pretty much standard.

On the Rpi:

```
#include <pigpio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <signal.h>

//g++ -Wall -pthread -o test test.cpp -lpigpio -lrt

std::atomic<bool> Quit = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(false);

void quit(int sig)
{
    Quit = true; //will require handler quit too
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    signal(SIGINT, quit);

    bsc_xfer_t xfer;
    gpioInitialise();

    xfer.control = (0x0A<<16) | 0x305; 

    int status = bscXfer(&xfer);
    if (status >= 0)
    {
        xfer.rxCnt = 0;

        while(!Quit)
        {
            status = bscXfer(&xfer);
            if(status)
            {
                if (xfer.rxCnt > 0)
                {
                    std::cout << std::endl << xfer.rxBuf;
                    memset( xfer.rxBuf, '\0', sizeof(char)*BSC_FIFO_SIZE );
                }
                else
                {
                    //std::cout<<"\n No datas";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"\nInit status error.\n"<<std::flush;
    }
    return status;
}
```

Any help on what Im doing wrong will be appreciated.

Edit: following Joan's answer I did swap the SDA & SCL to [ GPIO 18 & 19][1], and it works perfectly, solved fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think the information is "hidden".

E.g. http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#bscXfer

As far as I am aware all the pigpio API documentation says

> The BSC peripheral uses GPIO 18 (SDA) and 19 (SCL) in I2C mode

Comment: I must admit that I read that page and didn't find it, I blame my lack of sleep, testing that now

Comment: @Ebya That I understand.  It's easy to miss within the other text.  For examples it's often worth looking at the documentation for the other languages, in particular pigs or Python.  They are often more detailed than the C examples.

Comment: Just tested not receiving anything, joining  a picture to the OP in a minute or two.

Comment: disreagard comment, the doc doesn't refer to the gpio pin number but to the actual name of the pin... got it working

Comment: I'm stuck on how to properly send data as a slave, if you have an example on any languages, I'ld like a link

Comment: @Ebya See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/57093/13650

Comment: I saw that my only problem reside in ”bsc_i2c" not existing in C, or is it just the API ref missing it?

Comment: @Ebya It doesn't exist.  bsc_i2c is a trivial wrapper around bsc_xfer.

Comment: sorry to spam you, I'm stuck on updating the  txBuf for a week now, see my other question.